# Jenkins slowness, in AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, cicd

Hi I am facing slowness in Jenkins, my informations are ?Using AWS ec2 instance t2 large

**--------------------INSTALL JENKINS
----------------**

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo

sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key

sudo yum install jenkins -y

sudo systemctl enable jenkins

sudo systemctl status jenkins
sudo systemctl start jenkins
sudo systemctl stop jenkins

access JENKINS: http://your_amazon_linux_public_instance_ip:8080
```

**-------------------
UNINSTALL JENKINS
-------------------**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins
sudo yum remove jenkins
```

Everything works fine in the fresh installation but when I restart the EC2 instance then Jenkins performance goes down. Is it because in every restart the public IP getting changed and after installation Jenkins gives one URL to access and the url getting changed after restart.

eg :

**public IP of my EC2 instance** :[image: EC2 public IP]

**To access Jenkins**  [image: Complete URL of Jenkins]

**When I access first time Jenkins it gives us one url,:**

[image: After instalation of Jenkins]

But subsequent restart in EC2 instance changing the IP address, is it the reason behind the slowness of Jenkins? if yes then what was the solution for it?

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason behind this is the version of the Jenkins(2.440.2),so I install an older version and it is working fine.

```
 wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins-2.426.1-1.1.noarch.rpm
 sudo yum install jenkins-2.426.1-1.1.noarch.rpm
```